# How do I calculate my Black Blade's skills?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, character-advancement, magus

I am playing a [Bladebound Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/bladebound) in a campaign with very quick level advancement, necessitating frequent recalculation of my stats. The only part of my character advancement that's confusing me is calculating my Black Blade's skill ranks. From the PFSRD:

> Upon reaching an Intelligence of 12, it gains a bonus language of the GM’s choice, and gains 1 rank in Knowledge (arcana). Each time the sword **gains a bonus to Intelligence**, it gains another language and another rank in Knowledge (arcana). [Empahsis mine]

The wording of the second sentence is the issue and I feel as if I may be aproaching my advancement incorrectly. Does the way the entry is worded mean every time my Blade's INT **score** increases it gains another skill rank and language (ie. from 12 to 13 with no increase in modifier)? Or every time its INT **modifier** increases (ie. from 13 to 14 and from a modifier of +1 to +2)?

Comment: While I know this has been resolved, answers so far ignore a legalistic reading, like, for instance, the spell [*fox's cunning*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fox-s-cunning) that "grants a +4 enhancement bonus to Intelligence" therefore allowing the sword to gain 4 languages and 4 skill ranks *each time* the spell's cast on it (assuming the caster can figure out a way to target the sword). Would this sort of absurdist reading be useful or would it just muddy things?

Comment: The sword is explicitly not a living creature but an intelligent item, so I don't believe spells like Fox's Cunning would work on it. Otherwise I'd use that exact spell before every combat for more Arcane Pool points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PFSRD says this about [Attribute modifiers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Determine-Bonuses):

> Each ability, after changes made because of race, has a modifier ranging from –5 to +5. [...] **A positive modifier is called a bonus**, and a negative modifier is called a penalty.

Compare to these sections from [Black Blade Basics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/bladebound#TOC-Black-Blade-Basics):

> *Languages and Skills:* A black blade starts with Common as a language. As the black blade increases in Intelligence, it manifests knowledge of languages and arcane lore. Upon reaching an Intelligence of 12, it gains a bonus language of the GM’s choice, and gains 1 rank in Knowledge (arcana). Each time the sword gains **a bonus to Intelligence**, it gains another language and another rank in Knowledge (arcana).
>
> *Black Blade Arcane Pool:* A black blade has an arcane pool with a number of points equal to 1 + its **Intelligence bonus**.

Hence, you get extra skills every time the **bonus** (or **modifier**) increases (the same as with characters).

If it was every time the *score* increases, they would say "Each time the sword increases in Intelligence..." similar to the start of the Languages & Skills paragraph.

Also, it starts gaining skills at Int 12, ie Int **modifier (or bonus)** of +1

And, its Arcane Pool size is 1 + Int **bonus**. If this is not the same as Int modifier, then what is it? If this *is* the same as Int modifier, why isn't it in the previous paragraph?

Comment: Compare the use of "bonus" to that on the Eidolons page. The "STR/DEX Bonus" column doesn't mean that's what the stat's modifier becomes, it means they gain that bonus to their base stat. That's the logic I'm working under for advancing my Blade.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons

Comment: Added more references to support my argument

Comment: Also, the only "bonus" the Black Blade has in its table is Enhancement Bonus. Its int is just listed as "Int" not "Int bonus". It is different to Eidolons, because it doesn't have a "base stat + bonus", it just has "Int = this".

Comment: It would be "a bonus to its Intelligence modifier" then, but it isn't. That's why I'm certain the bonus is *to* Intelligence (score) itself, not a bonus to its bonus.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie How do you reconcile that with "A black blade has an arcane pool with a number of points equal to 1 + its Intelligence bonus"? How do you propose to calculate its pool size? What is its bonus if not its modifier? And if it means modifier in this paragraph, why do you think it means something else in the previous paragraph? And, why does it start gaining skills at Int 12 (= modifier, or bonus, +1)?

Comment: @Adeptus Because the words aren't the same: “bonus to Intelligence” and “Intelligence bonus” mean different things. As for why it only starts getting skills at Int 12 (i.e., Magus level 5): there's no obvious reason why that would be wrong, so it doesn't have any bearing on the issue.

Comment: [This post on Paizo forums](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mgky?Black-Blade-and-bonus-languages-and-skill-ranks), and [this one](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2orch?Skills-of-a-Black-Blade) agree with me (but with no response from Paizo... so, consensus but not official support)

Answer (score 8):

It's every time the blade benefits from this feature:

> *Intelligence*: This is the intelligence score of the black blade. It starts at 10 and **increases by 1 for every two levels of the bladebound magus** (at 3rd level, 5th level, and so on).

A very RAW reading could say that increases to the Int score from other sources would also count, sure, maybe — but that's a tangent and neither here or there. The point is that it's a clear reference to this part of [Black Blade Basics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/bladebound#TOC-Black-Blade-Basics).